# jquery plugin - how to make $(this) working in the context of a custom setting

Tags: jquery

Below is a very simplified version of an idea of what I want to do.

I am trying to set a custom option  like this below  but how do I use $(this) as its in the wring context. how do I write it so that the  main object gets the used and not the this in the function, right now I get a fnode error.

```
beforeDOTHIS: function () { 

                        $(this).css({color:'blue'});
                        alert($(this).text());

                    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dpeae/

HTML

```
<div>




    <div id="One">test1</div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <div id="Two">test2</div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <div id="Three">test3</div>


</div>
```

javascript

```
  /* To be moved to own custom js plugin file ------------------------------------------- */

                //custom plugin
                $.fn.addMySpan = function (customOptions) {

                    var defaults = {
                        textColor: "#033",
                        beforeDOTHIS: function () {}
                    };

                    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, customOptions);

                   return this.each(function () {

                       settings.beforeDOTHIS();

                  });

                };

        /* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/



        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#One,#Two,#Three').addMySpan({
                textColor: "red",
                beforeDOTHIS: function () { 

                    $(this).css({color:'blue'});
                    alert($(this).text());

                } 
            });




        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a reference to `this` then set it as the function's context with `call`:

```
            var self = this;

            var defaults = {
                textColor: "#033",
                beforeDOTHIS: function () {}
            };

            var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, customOptions);

            return this.each(function () {

               settings.beforeDOTHIS.call(self);

           });
```